# How to handle low-quality answers to old but popular questions

Tags: discussion

I recently came across this question in the "Low Quality Posts" review queue:

[How do I push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-to-push-a-new-local-branch-to-remote-repo-and-track-it-too)

This question is old, popular, protected, and has well accepted answers.

There are two new answers within the last month, which have multiple downvotes:

[image]

However, they don't meet any of the low quality criteria:

- These new answers are *not* commentaries on other posts.
- They are *not* "Thank you" comments.
- They are *not* "I'm having this problem too" comments.
- They are *not* a new or different question, posted as an answer.
- They are *not* link only spam posts.

They are just low quality answers.

My understanding is that normally the correct action in this situation is to downvote the answer and move along. However, this feels wrong in this situation due to the age and quality of both the original question and the accepted/other answers.

What is the correct course of action here?

Comment: (Wild guess for the downvotes) These answers don't seem to add anything new to the already existing ones.

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2566/168