# What could be done about low quality, highly visited questions?

Tags: discussion, statistics, data-explorer

I recently looked at the correlation of question score and question visits of non-closed, non-deleted questions. This is the 2D histogram (obtained via a [data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1182311/2d-histogram-of-question-views-vs-score)) with a logarithmic scale of the occurrences (46.2% of all non-closed questions have score 0 and the histogram with a linear color scale would show only a single visible peak at score 0).

[image]

The correlation between the question score and the view count is not very high (0.34) and there is a number of questions (in region marked with X in histogram) with a low score (<= 0) and at the same time a relatively high view count (>= 2000), which is much larger than the median view count of a question of ~300.

The low score might be an indication of low quality or low usefulness, but the high view count might be an indication of search engines thinking this content might be useful. Who's more right? The votes (or lack of positive votes) or the search engines bringing the traffic.

Some statistics about these questions:

- ~451k questions are in that region, that is ~2.5% of all non-closed questions.
- They account for ~1.9 billion views, that is ~4.6% of all views of non-closed questions.
- They are asked by ~291k different users.
- They have been voted only 95k times up and 173k times down, resulting in a net rep gain of 602k rep.
- The answers are less than average. An average non-closed question has a score of 2.31 and the sum of the scores of its answers is 4.98, while a question like here has an average score of -0.18 and the sum of the scores of its answers is 2.29. However there are answers and they are positively scored (otherwise the automatic deletion after 365 days might already have removed them).

Here is a top 10 of these questions, sorted by number of views, showing score, creation year and main tag:

- [Java program to find the largest & smallest number in n numbers without using arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21925830) score 0, views 198k, created 2014, Java
- [Prime numbers between 1 to 100 in C Programming Language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41444655) score -4 , views 144k, created 2017, C
- [linked list program to insert and delete nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16957728) score 0, views 134k, created 2013, C
- [Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value in SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28271414) score 0, views 129k, created 2015, SQL
- [Adding values to an array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15466205) score 0, views 123k, created 2013, Java
- [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20961074) score -2, views 120k, created 2014, Java
- [Install apk without downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10943037) score 0, views 113k, created 2012, Android
- [How to take character input in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22837423) score 0, views 112k, created 2014, Java
- [how to fix java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18823792) score -3, views 108k, created 2013, Java
- [How to read Data from Excel sheet in selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22689666) score 0, views 107k, created 2014, Java

The problems with these questions are in my opinion:

- A considerable chunk of these questions are incomplete debugging help questions that somehow feature the right keywords to make them search magnets; they actively "waste" the time of visitors and probably should be closed to a large extent or further downvoted.
- The search engines have their own view on what is useful and might not regard question score as a very relevant indicator of quality (for them). Maybe they should.
- Closing a large chunk of these questions is not feasible, even with 3 close votes for a single close and say 30k close votes per month this would take up to 3-4 years and nothing else would get closed in the mean time.
- Some of these questions might actually deserve a higher score (potentially after being polished) - maybe the search engines vote / the public interest wants to signal us something there.

**What else could/should be done with these low score, highly visited questions?**

Deleting them all sounds a bit too harsh and ignoring them feels like we continue wasting time of visitors. Evaluating them manually is a task that takes very long, probably too long. It makes sense to concentrate on the high views questions (maybe normalized by tag somehow) because there content curation actions have the highest impact. Maybe we could feed some of them to a review queue (low quality maybe?) starting with highest number of views downwards, now that the review activity has increased a bit. Or is there a way to tell search engines that score is important?

---

Related stuff on meta that come up in searches about "low quality questions, high number of views". They are mostly concentrating on low quality answers though.

- [Roomba when all posts have a strictly negative score](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377871/roomba-when-all-posts-have-a-strictly-negative-score) has not been done
- [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262077/what-should-the-system-be-deleting-automatically-that-it-already-isnt) would not include these questions with upvoted answers
- [What should be done about users who only post (low-quality) questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387728/what-should-be-done-about-users-who-only-post-low-quality-questions) was rejected
- [Threshold experiment results: closing, editing and reopening all become more effective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390083/threshold-experiment-results-closing-editing-and-reopening-all-become-more-eff) come up when searching about "low quality highly visited", it's however only about the close system
- [How to handle low-quality answers to old but popular questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253594/how-to-handle-low-quality-answers-to-old-but-popular-questions) concentrates on answers
- [Gamification rules have to be changed. Aiming quality, not quantity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256742/gamification-rules-have-to-be-changed-aiming-quality-not-quantity) concentrates on duplicates or canonical questions
- [We need better tools to prevent “long tail of crap” on popular questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390907/we-need-better-tools-to-prevent-long-tail-of-crap-on-popular-questions) deals mostly with low quality answers
- [We need more close votes!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285438/we-need-more-close-votes) closing that many questions isn't feasible even with more close votes

Comment: See my suggestion to [use low votes per view to raise for review as click-bait](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188004/use-low-votes-per-view-to-raise-for-review-as-click-bait).

Comment: @Raedwald Looks good to me. Unfortunately hasn't been done (or at least doesn't say so) and would probably not solve the problem completely. But may be better than nothing.

Comment: I have just downvoted some of them, and all of their answer as questions that bad should not be answered.  If a few more people did that they would be auto deleted

Comment: Perhaps trying to improve these questions would be a better idea than massively downvoting them if they're on-topic. I see most of the questions now have a substantially lower score than when this question was posted, and since they're attracting high amounts of views, they must be doing something right (or close them as a duplicate, if applicable)

Comment: @ErikA  Both seems to be the case. There are many offtopic questions that just didn't get closed. But there are also some questions that can be improved and be made more useful. After improvement maybe they would probably get upvoted. I like the name on Raedwald's linked MSE feature request. They are basically clickbait. The question is how best to either close them or improve them or tell search engines they are doing it wrong.

Comment: It strikes me that if these are the most popular questions but are the rating is lousy, perhaps its the rating system thats making the wrong call here.

Comment: @Shayne Could be although intuitively I would trust the human manual rating system more than the internet traffic. Algorithms like what powers search engines can err easily and we don't know how satisfied visitors were with what they saw.